# Facebook Integration in to android app

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Hi plan to develop an android app with Facebook log in for that i can download Facebook latest android sdk and import it into eclipse and create a project and Facebook sdk set as a library project and then create a layout with Facebook log in button widget and integrated it in to my main.xml file and store the app id in strings.xml and set this id in manifest meta-data tag but while implementing am not fully confused please help and give some sample code for step by step log in and click on loginbutton and then enter credentials like.

Comment: try this simple tutorial  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_facebook_integration.htm

Comment: i need login functionality for facebook

Comment: the facebook developer site provides step by step instruction on how you can achieve this. or do you need others to do the googling for you? forums are not for devs who needs to be spoon fed. try searching and get back here if you got stock while trying to implement it. a lot of devs will be happy to help you.

Comment: https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android
here is the complete solution of social authentication and othe operation use social auth library you can customize the library as per your requirement.

Comment: problem with once login after how can i show another screeen succes if login failed show failed screen.where i can check success login or failure thats the problem my side integration and all done.but always am getting state.isclose() in log

Answer (score 0):

for integrate your app with facebook you have to  first register your application then receive some application id then you have to download facebook sdk then add it into your project

for more detail refere following link:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_facebook_integration.htm
https://docs.mobage.com/display/WWNATIVE23/Integrating+the+Facebook+SDK+Android#IntegratingtheFacebookSDKAndroid-Step1